# How to pivot longer with the grouping notation at the center of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with the following column headers:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ABC1_1_1DEF = c(1, 2, 3),
  ABC1_2_1DEF = c(NA, 1, 2),
  ABC1_3_1DEF = c(1, 1, NA),
  ABC1_1_2DEF = c(3, NA, NA),
  ABC1_2_2DEF = c(2, NA, NA),
  ABC1_3_2DEF = c(NA, 1, 1)
)
```

I want to pivot the dataframe longer such that the middle number of each column is the group that contains the new columns:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  ABC1_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 3, NA, NA),
  ABC1_2 = c(3, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA),
  ABC1_3 = c(2, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1)
)
```

What's the best way to achieve this using R, ideally with `dplyr`?

Comment: Is your expected output correct? I don't get how you get `ABC1_2` and `ABC1_3` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine all the `ABC1_1`, `ABC1_2` and `ABC1_3` columns you can use -

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = everything(), 
                    names_to = '.value', 
                    names_pattern = '([A-Z]+\\d+_\\d+)')

#  ABC1_1 ABC1_2 ABC1_3
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1      1     NA      1
#2      3      2     NA
#3      2      1      1
#4     NA     NA      1
#5      3      2     NA
#6     NA     NA      1
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. What if I was interested in grouping by the third number instead? (I.e., the number right before DEF.)

Comment: Change `names_pattern` to `names_pattern = '[A-Z]+\\d+_\\d+_(\\d+)DEF'`